# Color a strings segments in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to take a string which is divided into segments by "-" character.

I need to find the "-" in each location and colour the segment for example the string is divided into

type-name-function-location

How do I break up each of those individual parts and add colour them?

Thank you

Comment: pls add an input and excepted output !

Comment: Currently the python script just lists a bunch of items all in the same format of "type-name-function-location" the output needs to be the same just coloured

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to install the [termcolor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) module to do this. Refer to the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) for more colors.

### Example:- 1 - Color the hyphen

```
>>> import termcolor
>>> string = "type-name-function-location"
>>> string = string.replace('-', termcolor.colored('-', 'red'))
>>> print string
type-name-function-location
```

This will replace `-` with red colored `-`.

#### Screenshot of the terminal:

[image]

---

### Example:- 2 - Custom color the segments of the string

**Note:** function `colorChanger` takes 5 inputs(`s`, `firstSeg`, `secondSeg`, `thirdSeg`, `fourthSeg`, `hyphen`) where `s` is a string, `firstSeg`, `secondSeg`, `thirdSeg` and `fourthSeg` is the color(string) to be assigned to the first, second, third and the fourth segment respectively and `hyphen` is the color to be assinged to hyphen `-`.

```
>>> import termcolor
>>> 
>>> def colorChanger(s, firstSeg, secondSeg, thirdSeg, fourthSeg, hyphen):
...     colors = [firstSeg, secondSeg, thirdSeg, fourthSeg]
...     frags = s.split('-')
...     for ind, color in enumerate(colors):
...         frags[ind] = frags[ind].replace(frags[ind], termcolor.colored(frags[ind], color))
...     return termcolor.colored('-', hyphen).join(frags)
... 
>>> string = "type-name-function-location"
>>> 
>>> print colorChanger(string, 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'magenta', 'cyan')
type-name-function-location
>>> print colorChanger(string, 'yellow', 'blue', 'cyan', 'red', 'grey')
type-name-function-location
```

#### Screenshot of the terminal:

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you example 2 really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will assign a random color to each text component:

```
from random import choice
import termcolor

s = 'hello-goodbye-world-42'
bits = s.split('-')
s = '-'.join(termcolor.colored(i, choice(termcolor.COLORS.keys())) for i in bits)
print(s)
```